# Is there a way to make a calculated field in Tableau that can be a reference line that move based on Criteria?

Tags: tableau-desktop

This is the calculated field that I have made to determine a goal line of 85% for call reachability and 95% for a chat reachability. However, if both are selected on the dashboard, I want the goal to go away. Is there anyway to do this?

If [Media Name] = 'Call' then .85
ELSEIF [Media Name] = 'Chat' then .95
else 0
END

Comment: when you say "selected" what do you mean? selected by the user, filtered, using parameters? try to be more specific in order to provide more context

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.